# PostGIS convert geography(Point,4326) to GPS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, gps, point

I got a database with a column of type geography(Point,4326), the data contained looks like `0101000020E610000092E057F66EF73140930035B56CBD4840`. How can I convert it to GPS coordinates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this column is in Well Known Binary (WKB) or Extended Well Known Binary (EWKB) Format. You should try to query it using something like:

```
select astext(your_column_name) from your_table_name
```

That will give you the textual representation. Not sure what you mean by GPS co-ordinates? Do you want to convert it into a `.gpx` file or just get the lat/lon. In which case the former will do that, although you might have to clean up the output in text editor or something.

The alternative would be

```
select ST_X(your_column_name),ST_Y(your_column_name) from your_table_name
```

which will give you the numeric lats and longs in two columns as your query table.

**---- EDIT**

These are functions on Geometry columns --- on Geography columns, the following is correct:

```
 select ST_AsEWKT(your_column_name) from your_table_name
```

Comment: What I mean by GPS coordinates is just lat/lon. I've tried the functions you proposed but both returned an error ERROR:  function astext(geography) does not exist
ERROR:  function st_x(geography) does not exist. Is there something I have to install to get it working?

Comment: Try ST_AsEWKT(your_column_name)

Answer (score 11):

The ST_X/ST_Y functions are only defined on the geometry type, so cast there before calling them.

```
SELECT ST_X(geogcolumn::geometry), ST_Y(geogcolumn::geometry) FROM thetable;
```

Comment: According to my tests (postgres 9.2, postgis 2.0.1), this is a bit faster than ST_AsEWKT