# Postgis How to populate column with geography data from geometric data?

Tags: postgis, coordinates, geography-data-type

I stored my point date in geometry format with SRID 4326 supposed EWKB (data looks like this "0101000020E610000071F1A611E9392640AECD10D8E68C4A40") =  way geometry(Point,4326)
I want to have the coordinates in geography format. So what to do?
So far I created another column for it:

```
ALTER TABLE brb_point ADD COLUMN geography geography(POINT,4326);
```

With this I get the coordinates shown:

```
ST_AsEWKT(way) from brb_point;
```

But I do not get along with the second step: populating the new column 'geography' with data from 'way' showing the coordinates with lon, lat.
Trials like this led nowhere:

```
UPDATE brb_point SET geography = ST_GeomFromEWKB((way), 4326);
```

I found a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65107/insert-geometric-data-to-a-column-from-coordinate-values-in-double-precision) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32680/postgis-convert-geographypoint-4326-to-gps), but I'm not sure how to use it in my case.

Comment: ST_GeomFromEWKB returns geometry, not geography. See the documentation for the function (http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_GeomFromEWKB.html), and this question for the difference between the two (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26082/what-is-the-difference-between-geometric-and-geographic-columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE brb_point SET geography = way::geography;
```